# How to do I retrieve the current time on a stopwatch?

Tags: java, android, textview

In short, how would I retrieve a time and display it on a Textview elsewhere? Like a variant to stop watch lapping that automatically updates some view when the timer stops?

If you know any resources on proper lapping or other examples of [android studio time tracking features](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) please include them.

Here is some working. java stop watch code:

```
package com.example.temp1.stackoverflowquestion;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


//Timer Text and Button
TextView txtTimer;
Button btn;

//Stop Watch logic
Handler handler;
long StartTime,timeInMilliseconds,TimeBuff,UpdateTime =0L;
int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer_Value);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart_Stop);
    btn.setText("Start");
    handler = new Handler() ;

    //start/stop timer and change text
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (btn.getText().toString() == "Start") {

                btn.setText("Stop");
                StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
            } else {
                btn.setText("Start");
                TimeBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        }
    });

}

//Stop Watch logic
public  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
     public void run() {
         timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-StartTime;
         UpdateTime = TimeBuff+timeInMilliseconds;
         Seconds=(int)(UpdateTime/1000);
         Minutes=Seconds/60;
         Seconds%=60;
         MilliSeconds=(int)(UpdateTime%1000);
         txtTimer.setText(""+Minutes+":"
         +String.format("%02d",Seconds)+":"
         +String.format("%03d",MilliSeconds));
         handler.postDelayed(this,0);
    }

};
}
```

Here's its .xml layout Code:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Timer_Value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart_Stop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. On click you have to call the text view and set text within it.

Here is an example that works in the code provided in the question, add it in the on click method:

```
txtView.setText(txtTimer.getText().toString());
```